# Cannot move to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new Frag2();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

I tried  above code to move from one fragment to another fragment. It works fine.But when I move to next fragment i need to go to the previous fragment.Can u help me to achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void name() {

        Fragment fragment=new Frag2();
         FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
```

Add this lines in your fragment. hen Add this line on your next fragment

```
public void goback() {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a   OnClickListener like this

```
 OnClickListener backClick = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        };
```

in onCreateView method of your Fragment set OnClickListener like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view;

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, null);

        btnBack = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(backClick);

        return view;
    }
```